# how to pre-create directories on linux for file storage

Tags: linux, bash, directory

looking for a way to pre-create directories on linux to be used to store a large number of files.

We will be generating file ids using a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID) - I need to keep a copy of these files on a linux web server.  I plan on using subdirectories to split up the files  (it's ext3)...  so for example, the filename  055c102b-62fb-4671-a3c7-68b9515ec53e.swf  would live in  /data/files/0/5/5/055c102b-62fb-4671-a3c7-68b9515ec53e.swf   (taking the first 3 characters as directory names)

My question is - how to create the /data/files/?/?/?/ directories ahead of time?  Where ? could be a-z or 0-9

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using Bash I think it is:

```
mkdir -p {{a..f},{0..9}}/{{a..f},{0..9}}/{{a..f},{0..9}}
```

Might make more sense to just to create them as needed though.

I think since it is hex, this gives 16^x directories for x = tree depth, but someone from stackoverflow can probably explain that better and/or confirm if that is accurate.

Comment: That's exactly it.

Comment: Very cool - thank you so much!  Works perfectly.  The reason I (think I) need to create them ahead of time is because the external process that will be uploading these files via scp/sftp assumes the directories exist.  Do you see any downsides to doing this?

Comment: I guess the only real downside that comes to mind is that maybe in theory access will be a tad bit slower as each level of the tree will be a little bit wider until it is full.  That sounds like BS to me though as a I type it (especially with dir_index enabled on ext3/4), so no, no real downside that I can think of.  I would recommend that maybe you go over to stackoverflow and ask if 3 is the right tree depth if you haven't already given that a lot of thought (Can't really hurt, at least not too much).